# play store: combine one-time in-app purchase and subscription

Tags: android, google-play

In the Android Play Store: Is it possible to distribute an app for free, but provide multiple in-app purchases to unlock features, and also combine a (yearly/monthly) subscription to unlock yet another set of features?

All information I could find was the explanation to use one of the billing methods, but I couldn't find any information about combining multiple billing systems in 1 app.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do whatever you want. Here's the documentation on subscriptions: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html and the Billing API for all the other things: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html